# Ошибка обработки условия сравнения строк

Tags: python

```
a="Hello"
b="World"
c="Hello"
d="World"
if a==b & c==d :
    print("success")
```

при запуске выдается ошибка:

> (unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str')

Answer (score 3):

Python3 не имеет логического оператора `&`, вместо оператора `&` поставьте `and`, вот так:

```
a="Hello"
b="World"
c="Hello"
d="World"
if a==b and c==d:
    print("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. для логических условий надо использовать `and` вместо `&&`

   ```
   if a==b and c==d
   ```
2. `&` - это побитовое "и" и в данном примере он может быть использован:

ошибка:

> unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

связана с тем, что оператор `&` имеет больший приоритет, чем оператор `==`, поэтому питон пытается выполнить операцию

```
b & c
```

но `b` и `c` - это строки, а для них оператора побитового "И" не существует

однако если правильно расставить приоритеты, то можно `&` применить:

```
if (a==b) & (c==d):
```

теперь сначала будут вычислены `a==b` и `c==d` и хотя они булевы, но булевы однозначно соотносятся с целочисленными значениями - `False` - `0`, `True` - `1`

потому что будут возможны 2 варианты:

- `a == b` и `c == d` - т.е. будет `1 & 1`, т.е. `1` и условие будет выполнено
- `a != b` и `c == d` - т.е. будет `0 & 1`, т.е. `0` и условие не будет
- `a == b` и `c != d` - т.е. будет `1 & 0`, т.е. `0` и условие не будет
- `a != b` и `c != d` - т.е. будет `0 & 0`, т.е. `0` и условие не будет

таким образом в данном случае будет выполнено логическое "И" между `0`/`1` и `0`/`1` и будет эквивалентна `if a==b and c==d:`